# OAuth2.0 for nopCommerce

Tags: android, swift, nopcommerce

I am trying to use nopCommerce API for one of our mobile app. We have successfully done with website.

For mobile app, first step to run the api is to get access token. To generate access token we understand we need to use oAuth 2.0. We successfully generate token using Postman.

For iPhone/ Android we are trying to generate token.

Could someone suggest what should we use? Do we need to use Google oAuth for nopCommerce access token?

Comment: For a mobile app, you need to code to generate the token and that you can use for consuming the APIs. I'm not sure what do you mean by *Do we need to use Google oAuth for nopCommerce* because you've already token now and you just need to pass to the server.

Comment: @Div : I am looking for `you need to code to generate the token`. Can you pass me link for sample? What I found are library for oAuth2.0 for Google authentication.

Comment: I recommended you to use [nopCommerce API plugin](https://github.com/SevenSpikes/api-plugin-for-nopcommerce), which will helps in api authentication. Here is the sample code for token generation https://github.com/SevenSpikes/nopCommerce-Api-SampleApplication

Comment: @Div : The sample they provided is for .NET. I am looking for sample in Swift or Java

Comment: What version of nopCommerce are you using? Also, you can create token via API, you should not write token generation code in your mobile app for security reason

Comment: @Div : Version 4.10

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know! Token creation and validation should be done on server only.

Comment: @Div : Is there ready API already or our developer have to make it?

Comment: @Div : We tried with Postman and it is successfull. So we was trying to get access token from mobile programming side.

Comment: I'm not sure what you have tried with Postman, but Postman doesn't responsible for generating tokens, it will just send http request and give you a result.

Comment: @Div : Is there ready API already or our developer have to make it?

Comment: If you're using the same plugin (upper link), then you'd need to create an API from a sample code, and it won't take much time!

Comment: @FahimParkar Did you ever figure this out? I am looking to do the same in swift. If so do you have sample code that you can share?

Comment: @CodeMan03 : nope. we create a token with validity of 15 years and using that. Token has to be created using API.